# element seems to be taking space when display: none

Tags: css

I have a page that displays correctly in Chrome, but not Firefox or IE.  It seems that an element that has display:none is taking up space & forcing some text to the right.

http://flybysouth.com/faqs/

This is a WordPress site, and I am using a premium theme with my own customization.  I have applied the following custom css in an attempt to remove the header-wrapper from the page.  I know it's overkill; I must be chasing the wrong element...

```
#header-wrapper,
#leader,
#leader .margin,
#leader .margin h1 { display:none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 0; height: 0; }
```

Any ideas what is causing the space in front of "What makes it white?"  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might have an uncleared float somewhere above the main content area, try adding `clear:both;` to #main-col:

```
#main-col {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```